# CSS broken after 2 lines (using same classes)

Tags: html, css

Have following strange issue, have 7 lines (same classes) but after 2 lines it's looks different.
I cannot find any problems in css or html, and this must be working in my opinion.

here the css:

```
.archive-items dl {
border-bottom: 1px solid #4F8FCC;
padding: 0 0 8px 0;
margin: 0;
width: 310px;
}

.archive-items dl:first-child {
border-top: 1px solid #4F8FCC;
padding-top: 5px;
margin: 20px 5px 5px 0;
}

.archive-items dl a {
color: #162E4F;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
}

.archive-items dl a:hover {
color: #B51E89;
text-decoration:underline;
}

.archive-items dl dt,
.archive-items dl dd {
margin: 0;
line-height: 1em;
height: 1em;
}

.archive-items dt {
color: #4F8FCC;
font-size: 0.9em;
padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
}

.archive-items dd {
padding: 0 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

here code:

```
<div class="archive-items">
<dl>
<dt class="datum">Jan 28, 2012</dt>
<dd class="link"><a href="#">Test</a></dd>
</dl><dl>
<dt class="datum">Jan 28, 2012</dt>
<dd class="link"><a href="#">Test</a></dd>
</dl><dl>
<dt class="datum">Jan 28, 2012</dt>
<dd class="link"><a href="#">Test</a></dd>
</dl><dl>
<dt class="datum">Jan 28, 2012</dt>
<dd class="link"><a href="#">Test</a></dd>
</dl><dl>
<dt class="datum">Jan 28, 2012</dt>
<dd class="link"><a href="#">Test</a></dd>
</dl><dl>
<dt class="datum">Jan 28, 2012</dt>
<dd class="link"><a href="#">Test</a></dd>
</dl><dl>
<dt class="datum">Jan 28, 2012</dt>
<dd class="link"><a href="#">Test</a></dd>
</dl><dl>
<dt class="datum">Jan 28, 2012</dt>
<dd class="link"><a href="#">Test</a></dd>
</dl><dl>
<dt class="datum">Jan 28, 2012</dt>
<dd class="link"><a href="#">Test</a></dd>
</dl><dl>
<dt class="datum">Jan 28, 2012</dt>
<dd class="link"><a href="#">Test</a></dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

Tested here http://jsfiddle.net/ZtVME/4/

here image what I see

[image: example]

Comment: It looks ok to me in jsfiddle. Can you clarify what looks wrong and what browser you are using? I have viewed this in Chrome.

Comment: @Digbyswift and Phoenix, see image added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this happens because the first `dl` has the following css:

```
.archive-items dl:first-child {
    border-top: 1px solid #4F8FCC;
    margin: 20px 5px 5px 0;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
```

If you change the `padding` of `.archive-items dl` to `padding: 5px 0 8px;` will be the same for all.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZtVME/6/

Answer (score 0):

It actually is not about the padding but about the margin you give to the :first-child.
In the answer from Sotiris the 2nd is still different than other dl's.

I'll just explain margin here.
Margin means something like: keep away this distance from other elements.
Let's say we have element A and element B. We give them both a margin of 30px. How far would they go from eachother? They would be 30px away from eachother and not 60px. Unless they are contained by a parent because you would be saying keep 30px space between the element and its parent. And the 2 parents would obviously not flow into eachother.

Using padding would increase the size of element itself and give you more control over it.

2 other things to keep in mind.
1: Giving a margin-top to the first (visual) element in the page will move the body element.
2: You don't need more than 1 DL in your example.